# How to serve ActiveStorage attachments under a subpath of the owner entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Here is what I would like to achieve. Given a model that has something like this

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :files
end
```

I would like to be able to serve the attachments as files under
`GET /mymodels/:id/files/:filename`
(filename includes the format as well).
Of course this assume that my application no duplicate filenames for a specific MyModel id.

Is there a specific way that is recommended to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config/routes.rb` fully supports non-resourceful routes (i.e., arbitrary URL). They support dynamic segments in a form like in your question:

```rb
get '/mymodels/:id/files/:filename', to: 'mymodels#serve_file'
```

Given the above route, hitting `https://my_app.com/mymodels/1/files/banana.txt` will send the request to to the `show_files` method on `MyModelsController` with params of:

```rb
{ id: 1, filename: 'banana.txt' }
```

The [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) has lots of documentation for non-resourceful routes.

**EDIT**: (the gist of the question was clarified)

If your intent is to automatically download the attached files when the URL is hit, your controller action might look like:

```rb
  def serve_file
    mymodel = MyModel.find(params[:id])
    blob = mymodel.files.blobs.find_by(filename: "#{params[:filename]}.#{params[:format]}")
    redirect_to blob.url
  end
```

You have to reconstitute the filename, since Rails will automatically split the terminating element in a path into `filename` and `format` parameters.

NB: I had some trouble in dev with `:local` storage getting `.url` to work, but this works fine with actual remote storage (S3, etc.).

If your intention is to display/manipulate the file within your app (i.e., not download), you should consider passing the filename as a query parameter rather than have it as the terminating element in the URI.

Comment: Hi thansk for the answer. I was aware of custom routes like this. What I wanted to know is how to return files that have been attached with `have_many_attached` from ActiveStorage using this type of routes.
Basically in this case what is the `show_file` implementation or is there a default (no extra code) way of doing it with ActiveStorage.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. They were very helpful